# Windows 8 - keyboard layout (input language) removes itself for unknown reason

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-layout, language, input-languages

Since a few weeks now, without any actions on my side, one of my three active input languages (keyboard layouts for German, English and Czech, in that order) somehow mysteriously removes itself randomly (always the English one, actually), not even on restarts or something.

Even stranger, all three languages are listed in `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload` and appear in the task bar's language selection, but at some point, English (in the middle of the three languages) disappears, so I cannot select it anymore using ALT + SHIFT. But when I go into the language settings and move English up or down, it's in the task bar again.

I tested if this happened after starting a program (Visual Studio in the tested case), but not even this seems to be the issue.

Does anyone have any idea, why this could have happend? Maybe a Microsoft update or something? I'd be very grateful, because this is really annoying.

Comment: It sounds like your selection is not actually saved at all, since it's not even shown in the task bar. Perhaps something has made it read-only? Perhaps related to user (admin) rights?

Comment: Well, I've got admin rights to the machine, but I don't get a confirmation hint when doing anything with the languages. But I wouldn't know how to "save" things there as you can only add, remove, move up and down languages. I've already removed and readded the respective language without any effect. Still, as mentioned, I didn't mess around with it before, yet some day, this problem arose...

Comment: Still noone who any further idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in the registry:

1. Open `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts` and find the number code
   of the language you want to add. Eg. En_UK = 00000809
2. Then go to `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload` and add a new String Value entry after the last existing one and make the number one higher than existing (eg. 1, 2, 3 exists --> name the new one "4").
3. Give the new entry the Data value of whichever language you want to add. If it is "En_UK" like in step 1, make the value "00000809"

Then I guess you need to log out and login again to make it active.

Comment: Better late than never. I just checked the registry for what you suggested. All three keyboard layouts are in the `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload` list and they get loaded on system start. So that does not seem to be the problem.